# Generate shared secret key using public and private key in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, public-key-encryption, diffie-hellman

Taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography 
[image]

> In the Diffie–Hellman key exchange scheme, each party generates a public/private key pair and distributes the public key. After obtaining an authentic copy of each other's public keys, Alice and Bob can compute a shared secret offline. The shared secret can be used, for instance, as the key for a symmetric cipher.

My question is, given the arbitrary public key (Bob's) and arbitrary private key (Alice's), how can we implement this function (derive the shared secret key offline) in C#?

```
private static SecretKey generateSharedSecret(PrivateKey private_key, PublicKey public_key)  
{
    //combine the keys
    return secretKey;
}
```

Comment: See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng(v=vs.110).aspx
and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24632/Shared-Key-Generation-using-Diffie-Hellman

Comment: By using [ECDiffieHellmanCng](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng(v=vs.110).aspx)object, for example

Comment: Ask this on the Security or CompSci site. It's off-topic here.